# how to use jQuery to show up a non-modal dialog?

Tags: jquery, dialog, plugins

Here is a plugin for block dialog:

http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#dialog

But what I need is a non-block dialog.

Is there such a plugin?

It should be as light as possible

Answer (score 9):

Here you go!

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: That is modal, you have to click the x to close.